# Upload Image in system_theme_settings form using Zen on Domain Access System

Tags: theming, media

I want to upload the image as the background in the settings page of the zen theme.

In zen , It's easy to add an extra field in the theme-settings.php and it's worked at the single site system.

However,I want to add this feature to the domain access Website.

And I got some error message.

I just write the code as belowed:

```
$form['background_file'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'managed_file',
    '#title'    => t('Background'),
    '#required' => True,
    '#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://theme/backgrounds/',
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('background_file'), 
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
    ),
  );
```

[image]

picture above appeared correct.

But when i push the upload button.

I got the error message belowed
[image]

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: system_theme_settings in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 806 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/official/includes/form.inc).
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'system_theme_settings' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 841 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/official/includes/form.inc).
> Notice: Undefined index: var in variable_realm_form_system_theme_settings_alter() (line 618 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/official/sites/all/modules/variable/variable_realm/variable_realm.module).
> Notice: Undefined index: background_file in file_ajax_upload() (line 271 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/official/modules/file/file.module).
> Notice: Undefined index: #suffix in file_ajax_upload() (line 280 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/official/modules/file/file.module).
> ```

and i really don't know how to fix that.

I just referenced the content below and i can't find the answer.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739345/drupal-7-retain-file-upload
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515221/is-there-a-proper-drupal-7-form-api-managed-file-tutorial
- http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/06/drupal-7-handling-file-uploads-and-moving-files-to-the-public-file-system
- [Is there a way to add managed_file field to theme-settings.php?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52769/is-there-a-way-to-add-managed-file-field-to-theme-settings-php)

Does someone fixed this situation before?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Working fine for me.. Where are you adding the code i mean in which file?

Comment: Looks like theme-settings.php

Comment: dammit! - works for me too. What is your Domain Access configuration looking like ?

Comment: Do you get these errors when you save the form without trying to upload an image ?

Answer (score 2):

The form needs to be able to find system_theme_settings() when getting rebuilt via ajax.

`form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'system', 'system.admin');` inside of theme-settings.php `hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
$form['theme_extra']=array(
    '#type'         => 'fieldset',
    '#title'        => 'Extra Image',
    '#description'  => 'Image Fieldset',
    '#collapsible'  => TRUE, 
    '#collapsed'    => FALSE,
    '#weight'       => -10,
  );     
$form['theme_extra']['background_file']=array(
        '#type'     => 'managed_file',
        '#title'    => 'test title',
        '#description' => 'description',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://theme/backgrounds/',
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('background_file'), 
        '#upload_validators' => array(
          'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
        ),
      );
```

This code !!

Comment: This is the actual answer... great job.