# How do I save a file with managed_file in a theme?

Tags: forms, files, 8

I'm developing a theme that it requires to have a header image on the front page, so I have this.

**casper.theme**

```
function casper_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

$form['theme_extra']['front_page_background_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Front Page Background Image',
    '#description' => 'Add background image for the front page',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#weight' => -4,
    '#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://theme/backgrounds/',
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('front_page_background_image' , 'casper'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
    ),
 );
}
```

However, after it, while the file been missing and after some reading, I find out that is because managed_file does not save your image permanent.

There are similar questions:

- [Is there a way to add managed_file field to theme-settings.php?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52769/is-there-a-way-to-add-managed-file-field-to-theme-settings-php) is specified to Drupal 7.
- [Drupal 8 Theme Header Background Image Upload](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142053/drupal-8-theme-header-background-image-upload) is using "file" type instead of managed_file. I already tried something similar to what the Mayo theme is doing, but I was not able to successfully figure it out.

How can I save my image permanently?

Answer (score 4):

The way it was done in Drupal 7 was that you wrote a function for `hook_form_submit` where you would

```
// Get the File ID (fid).
$fid = $form_status['values']['managed_file_field'];

// Load the file.
$file = file_load($fid);

// Set the status to permanent.
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

// Finally save the file.
$file->save();
```

You can read more about this with a great Drupal 7 example [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1090198#comment-5452200).
I'm sure there's something similar on Drupal 8. You'll just need to register a submit handler for the form. Take a look at the docs for managed_file if you want to go that route. [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/8#managed_file) for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a method that does exactly this. I can confirm that it does indeed work.

```
public static function saveFile($fid, $moduleName, $fileType){

  if(isset($fid) && is_string($fid)){

    /**
     * @var $file File
     */
    $file = File::load($fid);

    // save the file
    /**
     * @var $file_usage DatabaseFileUsageBackend
     */
    $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
    $file_usage->add($file, $moduleName, $fileType, 1); // or $themeName

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey Adrian, this seem like is specify to a module and I'm trying to use it with a theme. In order for me to give you the bounty you need to show using it snipped of code in the question. =) So how can I use that method with the snipped of code in my question ?

Comment: I think you can still specify submit callbacks in the $form array that you have. Such as `$form['#submit'][] = 'casper_form_submit'`, and then you could do something similar to the above.

Answer (score 0):

While I had thought that you could include a submit callback string, it looks like the theme file is not included when the form is submitted. This can be worked around dirty by making the submit callback a function in the form callback. Closures won't work because they cannot be serialized.

```
// @todo Please fix me, Drupal-Core Kenowbi!
$submit = function($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValue('front_page_background_image', []);
  if ($values) {
    $fid = $values[0];
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
    $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
    $file_usage->add($file, 'casper', 'theme', 1);
  }
};

$form['#submit'][] = $submit;
```

Realistically this seems like a good case for a core fix or a contrib module that would provide a way for themes to call their own submit callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Drupal 7

I used many places file_managed  to save my files. 
Please find the below code in my bartik theme, working fine:

**bartik.info**

```
settings[front_page_background_image] = headerimage.png
```

**template.php**

```
function bartik_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

$form['theme_extra']['front_page_background_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Front Page Background Image',
    '#description' => 'Add background image for the front page',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#weight' => -4,
    '#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://theme/backgrounds/',
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('front_page_background_image' , 'bartik'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
    ),
 );

}
```

**page.tpl.php**

```
$file =  file_load(theme_get_setting('front_page_background_image')); 

$image = image_load($file->uri); 

$content = array(
        'file' => array(
            '#theme' => 'image_style', 
            '#style_name' => 'large',
            '#path' => $image->source, 
            '#width' => $image->info['width'], 
            '#height' => $image->info['height'],
        ),
        );
echo drupal_render($content);
```

Comment: This question is for Drupal 8. And your answer if for Drupal 7.