# Custom submit handler for theme settings form

Tags: theming, 8

I am creating a new D8 theme and having slideshow functionality in it. For slideshow, we have title, description and image field in the theme settings form. I am able to alter the theme setting form using `THEME_NAME_form_system_theme_settings_alter`, but when I add a custom submit handler the form seems to break and get internal server error.

My objective for adding custom submit is to make the uploaded files status as permanent.

Here is my code,

```
function THEME_NAME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_settings_form_submit'; //tried this as well
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_custom_settings_form_submit';
}

function _custom_settings_form_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  for ($i = 0; $i <= SLIDESHOW_COUNT; $i++) {
    if (isset($values['slide_image_path' . $i]) && !empty($values['slide_image_path' . $i])) {
      // Load the file via file.fid.
      $file = file_load($values['slide_image_path' . $i][0]);
      // Change status to permanent.
      $file->setPermanent();
      $file->save();
      // $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
      // $file_usage->add($file, 'user', 'user', $account->id());
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE:
This is the error present in apache error log:
`PHP Fatal error:  Invalid placeholder (!message) in string: %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file). in /core/lib/Drupal/Component/Render/FormattableMarkup.php on line 240`

Does anyone have any idea where I'm doing it wrong? or is there any workaround for making the file status permanent?

Comment: Check watchdog, you'll see what the replacements mean.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked, but there was nothing regarding this, then only I looked at apache log.

Comment: Check the DB directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save a file with managed\_file in a theme?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186982/how-do-i-save-a-file-with-managed-file-in-a-theme)

Answer (score 1):

From [Drupal 8: Use Custom Submit Handler for Theme Settings Form](http://kb.detlus.com/articles/drupal/drupal-8-use-custom-submit-handler-for-theme-settings-form/):

Use this method to add custom submit handler for theme settings form in drupal 8.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter().
 */
function MY_THEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $theme_file = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MY_THEME') . '/MY_THEME.theme';
  $build_info = $form_state->getBuildInfo();
  if (!in_array($theme_file, $build_info['files'])) {
    $build_info['files'][] = $theme_file;
  }
  $form_state->setBuildInfo($build_info);

  $form['#submit'][] = 'MY_THEME_form_system_theme_settings_submit';
}

function MY_THEME_form_system_theme_settings_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // TODO: Extra submssio logic.
  // This submit handler will be called before default submit handler for this form.
}
```